# Python Better Performance With Long Scripts or Wide Scripts?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, nested

Concerning imported dictionaries into python scripts, I've built a few humongous ones. The way I build them was lists nested in dictionaries:

```
Dictionary = {
    'Key1':{SubKey1:['Ya','Da','Ya','Da','Ya','Da',]}
    }
```

That's the general idea above. Now the dictionaries have gotten quite wide (as in length of a single line). Imagine repeating that SubKey a few thousaand times in the same line. Now I can easily split the SubKeys or the lists into separate lines. This will create a longer (row wise) file, but slimmer (column wise).

I'm wondering if there are any performance issue's when considering the Rows versus Column's Dilemma?

Comment: Formatting issues like this only matter once the file is parsed, and even then, splitting each entry onto its own line won't affect parsing performance. Once the code is actually executing, it literally doesn't matter.

Comment: There might be linguistic confusion between "text rows/columns" vs "data layout in row-major/column-major".

Answer (score 3):

Line length has no influence on Python performance. At all.

Keep line lengths short to maintain readability instead. See [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

Comment: @CodyBrown: there are no columns here, you keys? Key length has almost no influence on performance.

Comment: @CodyBrown: if you mean how many level deep your dictionary is nested, then every nesting costs you a very small step in looking up the key. You should instead benchmark your algorithms and code maintainability, not worry about dictionary lookup costs.